# How Can I put some filter string into my sql in playframework with the driver of scalikejdbc

Tags: postgresql, playframework

I want to count the people in my city with some filter

```
val filter = sex match{
    case "all"=>""
    case "men" => "where sex = 'men'"
    case "women" => "where sex = 'women'"
}
sql"""
    select * from users $filter
   """.map{...}.apply
```

but it's error like this

```
SELECT * FROM users 'where sex = 'women''
```

the filter string is just a string which is not I need.
How could I sovle this preblem?

Comment: You can't use arbitrary where-clauses with prepared statements. It will analyze your parameters and choose automatically the appropriate type to insert your value (in order to protect you from attacks like SQL injections, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use two different queries:

```
val results = sex match{
    case "all"=>sql"""
    select * from users""".map{...}.apply
    case _ => sql"""select * from users where sex = $sex""".map{...}.apply
}
```

or use the appropriate parameters:

```
val filter = sex match{
    case "all"=>"%"
    case "men" => "men"
    case "women" => "women"
}
sql"""
    select * from users where sex = $filter
   """.map{...}.apply
```

Comment: thanks a lot . you mean there is not a correct way to deal with this problem?

Comment: If you by "correct" you mean with the whole were-clause as a parameter, then, yes. That's not possible.